# Suggestion for a scale run

Tags: guitar

I can't get an F major scale run without screwing it up at the moment where I slide to F note on 10th fret of G string. First run is E Mixolydian – goes just fine. Second – F Ionian – can't get it. 1st, 2nd and 4st 16th note triplets are played with following pattern (hit, hammer-on, hammer-on) except that 3rd one that shifts position (hit, hammer-on, slide). Maybe you can suggest me something about how to better play it without messing up the note sound and scale structure. Here's the run (second one after 4/4 bar rest) that I've written a tab for.[image: run].

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to play it at tempo without working up to it?

This is always the problem.  Regardless of how skilled you might be every new thing needs to be "programmed" into muscle memory, even if it seems like it should be easy.

Also, you have provided great detail regarding how you attack these notes but not where the real problem seems to be.  For example, is it your left hand fingering that gets screwed up or the right hand has a hard time attacking the next pattern after the slide?  Or, is it synchronization between the two hands?

No matter what the issue the process for getting it clean is (1) slow it down very slow, (2) drill the problem spot until you cannot do it wrong, (3) start speeding up, (4) when you get to a speed where it breaks down back off and start going up 2 down 1 in speed until you fly past the speed where it breaks down.

You may be looking for a new fingering or advice to eliminate the slide (which I might try).  But the fact is if you are patient you can train yourself to play this at tempo.

You could help us help you by answering the questions I've posed in the comments and I'll update my answer to address them.  Last but not least, is this an original composition or a cover tune?  Are you trying to arrange something and you have freedom to do what you want or do you need to be on point with this tab?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is an original tune, not cover. So the problem is: I have bad accuracy with my ring to picky finger switch combination, so triplets 1 and 2 have index-middle-picky, while triplet 3 has that malicious switch to index-ring-picky combination. I tried to to play everything with index-middle-ring, but I don't have enough stretch. The problem in F Ionian is that I'm actually playing a major 7th note (E) instead of dom 7 note in E Mixolydian, which takes right in position for the 1 fret shift on B string. Here, I can't stretch to 9th fret with my middle finger, so I fail.

Comment: If you could replace that slide, that would be great. P.S. I tried to use the scale form of F Ionian on 13th fret, but then I can't get back to playing chords on 7th fret in time.

Comment: You need to drill he finger combination until it's easy.  Do you regularly practice or just jam and write sings?

Comment: Regularly practice – yes, 5h a day regularly.

Comment: But is your practice just playing or basic exercises.  A lot of young musicians think that jamming is practicing but basic fundamental skills need daily drilling.  So, 5h a day is how many hours basic skills vs how many hours playing songs?

Comment: Like, 1 hour of exercising, hour of chords, 1.5 hours songs, 1 hour technique (usually 40 mins is scales and so called "fretboard" harmony) and 30 minutes of slide guitar.

Comment: To tell you the truth I'd get rid of the slide and just play it straight, maybe with the hammer on's.  It's a pattern in the Mixolydian mode (right?).  I would have assumed you put the slide in for tone, or phrasing.  But if not just finger it (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 4).

Comment: Ok, the solution was to practice the slide with ring finger, so (1 [hammer], 2 [hammer], 4), (1 [hammer], 2 [hammer], 4), (1 [hammer], 3 [slide], ...), (1 [hammer], 2 [hammer], 3). 1,2,3,4 numbers of fingers.

Comment: If that works then great.